# Springboot kafka consumer not receiving messages after another has already received the message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am new to KAFKA and would like help

I have 2 applications (springboot), they are identical/copies only with different ports.
http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:8081/

**They are both consumers**

**the two listen to the topic XXX**

- - 

I have another APP that plays the role of producer.

whenever I send something to topic XXX.

only one of them consumes the message and the other does not.

I have tested both individually and they listen normally if they are listening alone, but if they are listening together only one of them will listen.

I'm using

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers=type
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.ackEachRecord=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.enableDlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.standardHeaders=both
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.dlqName=api***.d**.api***
```

my listener

```
@StreamListener(target=SomeString.TOPIC, condition = "headers['type']=='***' or headers['type']=='***'")
    public void handle(GenericMessage<String> message) throws BusinessException {
   
***
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Apache Kafka Binder implementation maps each destination to an
> Apache Kafka topic. The consumer group maps directly to the same
> Apache Kafka concept. Partitioning also maps directly to Apache Kafka
> partitions as well.

check kafka consumer group behavior -> https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_group.id

if kafka consumers have same groupId just one of listen message, you should give them different groupId

app in 8080 -> `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.group=consumer-group-1`

app in 8081 -> `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.group=consumer-group-2`

Comment: yea! you're right now it works.

imagining that the load balance will multiply my app several times, is there any way for this value to be variable?

Comment: spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.group=${random.uuid}